# Explicit casting and reassigning

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, object-oriented-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
class A{}

class B extends A{

public static void main(String args[]){
   A exampleA = new A();
   B exampleB = new B();
   exampleB = exampleA;  // compile error}
```

I understand why this results in an error, because you need explicit casting. However, I do not understand why I get a compile error with the following code:

```
class A{}

class B extends A{

public static void main(String args[]){
   A exampleA = new A();
   B exampleB = new B();
   exampleA = exampleB;
   exampleB = exampleA;  // compile error
```

From my point of view, The pointer exampleA now points to the same object as exampleB does, which is an object of class B. Moreover, because of reassigning the pointer exampleA, I interpret the last line of code as equal as exampleB = exampleB; The compiler disagrees and I fail to think as the compiler. Can someone tell me why I get an error?

I also used the getClass method for both classes and the output shows that both indeed point to the same object. Therefore, i am confused.

I am new to programming and would like to know more about how the compiler thinks. Aside from answering the question, any tips on books or other sources to distinguish between compiler and runtime logic would be of great help!

Note that I know how to solve the second block of code, which is just by doing explicit casting.

Comment: "because you need explicit casting" You'd get a `ClassCastException` at runtime if you did that: all `B`s are `A`s, but not all `A`s are `B`s.

Comment: The Java compiler doesn't track values through your code: it just takes them at face value. You simply can't assign an `A` to a `B` without casting it; and this might fail at runtime if it's not actually a `B`.

Comment: Yes I forgot about that, I would get a ClassCastException in runtime because during initialization, they are not related to each other.

Still, that does not answer my question why I would get a compile error. Why doesn't the compiler see it?

@AndyTurner: your second comment answered my question partially. Thank you. How do I learn how to isolate logical tracking from what you call face time? Any books that help me with that?

Comment: I think you may be confused about the point of casting. Casting doesn't change the type of one object to another, it's just a way of letting the compiler know that a value is in fact a particular subtype. In your case, a smart compiler might *theoretically* be able to deduce that `exampleA` points to an object of type `B`, but the Java compiler doesn't do that, since in most cases, only the runtime can definitely tell the type of an object.

Comment: "Still, that does not answer my question why I would get a compile error" because... it might fail at runtime, so you have to explicitly cast it - having checked that the cast will succeed, of course.

Comment: @shmosel "Casting doesn't change the type of one object to another, it's just a way of letting the compiler know that a value is in fact a particular subtype." 

Excellent explanation, I was indeed confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't detect that situation automatically.  It should work if you down-cast it explicitly. Then you are taking responsibility for making sure that the right side object can be down-cast safely.

Down cast by putting `exampleB = (B) exampleA;`.

If you do this and it cannot be down-cast, you'll get an exception at run-time.

Also, there are no "pointers" in Java.  References are similar but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to know about the compiler, so I'll put as much of that here as I can. The java compiler in java is a lot more trusting than some believe. This is an excellent case, because java allows you to construct artificial casting mechanisms, albeit with great difficulty in most cases. As such, the compiler takes a step back here and trusts that you know what you are doing. Runtime, obviously, is where things go awry in the most fantastic fashion, and it sees in action that no, that cast is not possible. 
In this specific case, class A obviously cannot downcast to become an example of class B. However, switch the last two lines around, and I believe you'll find that no errors take place. This is because class B most certainly can become an example of Class A, and when you set eB as an example of class A, and set eA to equal B, you'll find both end up as examples of class A.

```
class A{}

class B extends A{}

public static void main(String args[]){
    A exampleA = new A();
    B exampleB = new B();
    exampleB = exampleA;
    exampleA = exampleB;  // compile error should be fixed
}
```

EDIT: 
I realized I was wrong. See the comments below for details. Here is my corrected version.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A eA = new A();
    B eB = new B();
    A newAfromB = eB;
    eA = newAfromB;
}
```

Comment: Hi Siris, thank you for your answer. Can you show me in code what you mean with: However, switch the last two lines around, and I believe you'll find that no errors take place. This is because class B most certainly can become an example of Class A, and when you set eB as an example of class A, and set eA to equal B, you'll find both end up as examples of class A.

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry! I edited it, but I guess it didn't stick. I'll try again. Gimme a minute.

Comment: Wait a minute. I'm sorry. I forgot - you need a new declaration to upcast. I was wrong.

Comment: It's up there. Check it out at your leisure.

Answer (score -2):

You right about objects - they have the same type.

But! pointers still have different types.

So, thats why this error.